# What is the bot variant for message.bot.username?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I was upgrading a ban command for my Discord bot (Discord.js). This is my command now (without some unnecessary code):

```
  const target = message.mentions.users.first();
  if (target) {
    const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
    memberTarget.ban();
    message.channel.send(
      `<@${memberTarget.user.id}> got 360 no-scoped by ${message.bot.username}`
    );
  } else {
    message.channel.send(process.env.MSGERR);
  }
},
```

The problem here is that `message.bot.username` is not working. I have multiple bots, so I would like the bot username as a variable. When I tried `message.author.username`, it does work.

So my question is what is the bot variant of the `message.author.username`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the User object of the client, then access the username. You can get the client from `message.client`

```js
const { username } = message.client.user;

// Same as 
const username = message.client.user.username;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get your bot username on discord.js v13 you can use: `client.user.tag` instead of `message.bot.username`